# Sending metrics data from on-premise Linux server to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, on-premises-instances

To send on-premise server metrics to Cloudwatch, do I need direct connect or a AWS VPN to connect my on-premise server to AWS ?

I haven't yet tried anything. This is just for planning purpose. We will start sending metrics to Cloudwatch in a few days.

Comment: Don't tthink so.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-premise.html